# What does a constant that begins with a '#' and/or ends with a 'c' mean in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I need to compile an old Fortran program that previously used a Compaq Fortran compiler.  I can't seem to figure out what a constant that begins with a '#' is. gfortran says its a syntax error and I can't seem to find many answers.

```
CHAR2 = IATA(KK) - #20202030
CHAR3 = IATA(KK+1) - #20202030
```

What kind of constant is `#20202030`? According to the comments this code should take two ASCII characters in IATA and convert them to binary. Can someone explain this?

Further down:

```
IF (IATA(KK+1) .EQ. #2020202C) THEN
```

Now there is a 'C' at the end. What does that mean?

How can I port this over to gfortran? It feels like I'm missing something obvious. Please enlighten me.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually things that begin with # are in hexadecimal code, but still as I know nothing about fortran I can't tell you anything definite.

Comment: I was thinking something like that, but from what I've found Fortran hex constants begin with a 'Z'. I should have prefaced this by saying I know nothing about Fortran as well. Only what I've learned in the last day trying to compile this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking at is non-standard Fortran.  In Compaq Fortran the `#` is used to prefix a hexadecimal constant, as one of the comments suggests.  As the other comment suggests the standard prefix for hexadecimal constants is Z and the digits should be enclosed in '' marks. So non-standard `#2020202C` should translate to standard `Z'2020202C'`.

As for the trailing `C`, I think that's just a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: You sir, have just made my day. The old developer is long gone, and surprisingly I couldn't google an answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

Just a comment:

Besides being hexadecimal literals in non-standard notation, these are also ASCII strings fitted into 32-bit integer values. When stored in memory `#20202030` is `'___0'` or `'0___'` depending on the endiannes of the architecture while `#2020202C` is `'___,'` or `',___'` (underscores represent blanks). Padding with blanks is standard Fortran behaviour and storing 8-bit charaters into 32-bit types padded with blanks instead of NUL-s, e.g. using `#20202030` instead of `#00000030`, should come as no surprise to Fortran programmers.

In C and C++ subtracting `'0'` from another character is a very common way to convert characters like `0`, `1`, `2` and so on to their numeric equivalents (that absolutely fails to work with special Unicode symbols). E.g. `'9' - '0'` gives `9` since the ASCII code of `9` is 0x39 (57) while the ASCII code of `0` is 0x30 (48). Fortran does not treat `CHARACTER` as integers the way C and C++ do and one has to use `ICHAR()` or `IACHAR()` to covert them to their ASCII codes but still this code works much like a C/C++ one would do.

How is the `IATA` array defined? How are values assigned to its elements?

Comment: Thanks for the post, I wish I could select two answers. The first I found of IATA was in a common block: `COMMON /FFDTA/IATA(2800),A,B,C`. I think that just means its a generic array, but I can't find it being assigned to anywhere in the source file. It's only included in branch statements and accesses. Are common blocks visible to other source modules by default?

Comment: Common blocks are always visible to other modules. They are even visible to modules written in other languages that suport external symbols (e.g. C/C++). If `IATA` is not defined anywhere else then it is an array of `INTEGER` (unless implicit name to type mapping is changed with `IMPLICIT`).

Comment: Also common blocks only name a shared portion of the memory. You can give different names to variables stored inside a common block in different subroutines that use it (and even different variable types, which is a source of many subtle errors). This means that you can have a subroutine that has `COMMON /FFDTA/ASD(2800),X,Y,Z` and still `ASD` will refer to the same memory place as `IATA` does.

Comment: Well, I've already found that many other source files reference IATA, so I have a lot of work to do. This is enormously helpful for someone in my situation. Much appreciated!